# At the start of the execution of SDDP.jl, when there is no value approximation & terminal states available, what cost-to-go estimation is used?

Tags: julia, stochastic-dual-dynamic-programming, sddp

I am using SDDP.jl for my research and want to know that at the very start of the execution, when there is no value function initialization and terminal state (for backward recursion), how cost-to-go function is initialized?

In other words, what cost-to-go function is optimized at the very first forward pass in SDDP.jl implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is initialized with `theta >= lower_bound` or `theta <= upper_bound`, where `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` is passed as the argument to `SDDP.PolicyGraph(; lower_bound = 0) do sp, t ... end`.

This tutorial explains the algorithm: https://sddp.dev/stable/explanation/theory_intro